# Operator overloading : cannot add two pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operator-overloading, fractions

I created a Fraction class that is has member functions to add, subtract, multiply, and divide between two Fraction Objects along with the required default and copy constructors.

For this problem, I must used pointers (cannot use vectors!) because the Fraction objects can only be created if the user chooses to. In short, the pointer declaration and new initialization are in difference scopes.

I am trying to also overload the operator=, operator+, operator-, operator*, and operator/ to accept something like the following.

```
Fraction* fr1 = new Fraction(1,2);

Fraction* fr2 = new Fraction(3,4);

Fraction* fr3 = new Fraction();

fr3 = fr1 + fr2;
```

My current overloaded operator= member function looks like so:

```
    Fraction* Fraction::operator=(const Fraction*& fr) {


      num = fr->num;

      denom = fr->denom;

      return this; 
    }

    Fraction* Fraction::operator+(const Fraction*& fr) const {

      int gcd = gcdRecurEuclid(num * fr->denom + denom * fr->num, denom * fr->denom);

      Fraction* temp;

      temp = new Fraction((num * fr->denom + fr->num * denom) / gcd, 

                          (denom * fr->denom) / gcd);

      return temp;
    }
```

I keep getting the error '+' : cannot add two pointers, which most likely means my overloaded operator+ is not written correctly (and/or my overloaded assignment operator).
What do I need to do to correct this? Again, my instructor wants me to work with pointers, and does not want me to pass nor return copies of anything. I either need to pass by reference (or pointer? similar thing?).

Comment: @JesseGood: No it doesn't.  You can subtract one pointer from another.  Or you can add an integer to, or subtract an integer from a pointer.  But you can't add two pointers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, thank you for correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, trying to use arithmetic operators on pointers will result in the compiler trying to do pointer arithmetic. To call your own overloaded operator on a pointer, you can either do

```
Fraction *f, *g; // allocated with new
f->operator+(*g); /// Urgh!
```

or, almost as ugly

```
Fraction *f, *g;
(*f) + (*g);
```

One easy way to make this a bit nicer is to declare three new reference variables like this:

```
Fraction& f1 = *pfr1;
Fraction& f2 = *pfr2;
Fraction& f3 = *ptr3;
```

Where the `pfrN`s are the pointers to your fractions. Now if you use the reference variables, your overloaded operators will be called correctly, and you don't need to put in all the extra asterisks. The references will disappear at the end of the scope, and probably won't use any extra memory in your programme. You still need to `delete` the original pointers though!

Comment: That is an awesome idea! I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Another error persists. This time, the overloaded assignment operator= does not work.

Comment: Nevermind! I did something really stupid. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you overload a binary operator, (such as `operator+`) as a member function, the left hand argument needs to be an object (not a pointer) of the class which you are overloading the operator for.  If you want to do it some other way, you need to do it as a free function, taking two arguments, like this:

```
Fraction * operator+(const Fraction * lhs, const Fraction * rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

However, **this function signature is not legal**.  You cannot write an operator overload which takes only pointer arguments.  At least one of the arguments needs to be a user defined type (i.e. class, struct).  That's just the rules of the language.

Talk to your teacher and get clarification about exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @user2967424: The type of the left hand argument is implicit, correct.  However, I'm at a loss as to how you get from that fact to *"it is absolutely fine to use a pointer of an object"*.  The type of the left hand argument of a member binary operator is, implicitly, an object of the class for which the operator is a member of.  So, in your case, it is a `Fraction` object, not a pointer to a `Fraction` object.