# Overloading operators for nodes of a graph

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to define addition for two nodes of a graph by overloading the `+` operator. However, I get the following error which I do not understand:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘Node*’ and ‘Node*’ to binary ‘operator+’
   30 |     c = a + b;
      |         ~ ^ ~
      |         |   |
      |         |   Node*
      |         Node*
```

I tried to perform addition on two graph nodes by implementing the `add()` method which seems to work fine. Why does the same approach doees not work when I try to implement `operator+()`?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    public:
        double data;
        Node () {}
        Node (double x) : data(x) {}
        Node* add(Node *rhs);
};

// Works
Node* Node::add(Node *rhs) {
    Node* value = new Node();
    value->data = this->data + rhs->data;
    return value;
}

// Does not work
// Node* operator+ (Node* lhs, Node* rhs) {
//     Node* value = new Node();
//     value->data = lhs->data + rhs->data;
//     return value;
// }

int main(void) {

    Node* a = new Node(2.0);
    Node* b = new Node(3.0);

    Node* c = nullptr;
    c = a->add(b); // this works
    // c = a + b;  // does not work
    std::cout << c->data << "\n";

    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the example above with

`g++ -std=c++20 -O -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic graph.cc`

Comment: `a` and `b` are pointers. Your operators are for `Node`s not for `Node*`. You cannot overload `+`  for pointers

Comment: Why are you using pointers here? There's no need for that, nor what is expected. I also recommend you take some time to read [this canonical implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) reference for overloading operators.

Comment: `Node* a = new Node(2.0);` -- This looks like a C#, Java, or Python programmer's attempt to write C++ code without learning C++ properly.  There is absolutely no need to be using `new` here:  `Node a(2.0);` -- same with the other line of code.  Then `Node* Node::add(Node *rhs)` -- could simply be: `Node& Node::add(const Node& rhs)` that returns a reference to the newly added `Node`.  The client code shouldn't be in the business of supplying your class `Node` pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you please point me to a reference where I can learn C++ properly? I thought that using `new` would allow me to allocate memory on the heap which I want as the graph can become very big. Can you please show me a better approach that also works for large graphs?

Comment: You can allocate object on the heap, but don't model your overloaded operations on the pointers. If `a`, `b` and `c` are pointers then instead of doing `c = a + b` then dereference the pointers like `*c = *a + *b`. And make sure that the `+` operator really makes sense for your use-case. Remember, the operators should deviate too much from the semantics of the built-in operators.

Comment: @Gilfoyle Create an actual `Graph` class that has as member functions `addNode(const Node& n);`.  Then all of that `new` calls are within the `Graph` class itself, and not on the client using `Graph`.  Then the code would be as simple as `Graph g;  g.addNode({23});, which would tell `g` to add a `Node` with data of `23`.  Also, your `Node` class fails to initialize `data` in the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to overload the + operator for pointers (this would interfere with normal pointer arithmetic, see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850991/operator-overloading-cannot-add-two-pointers)). Hence, the overloaded function needs to take `Node` values or references.

The `Node` class in the question is sufficiently tiny that it is not worth using dynamic memory allocation nor passing objects by reference.

All in all, the implementation can be modified as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    public:
        double data;
        Node () {}
        Node (double x) : data(x) {}
        // friend Node operator + (Node a, Node b); // Would be needed if "data" was private or protected
};

Node operator + (Node a, Node b)
{
    return Node(a.data + b.data);
}

int main(void) {

    Node a(2.0);
    Node b(3.0);

    Node c = a + b;
    
    std::cout << c.data << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Node class is tiny, but I want to create a very big graph that holds a large number of nodes. Therefore I wanted to allocate heap memory. Would that be possible with your approach?

Comment: @Gilfoyle Yes and no. Some design decisions have to be made which are not so "one choice fits all". One approach would be to have 3 classes: a `Graph` class containing `Node` objects each containing a `Data` element and the connections of the node. The `Data` class could then look like the `Node` class above. Nodes could then be allocated on the heap and data manipulation done with the approach in this answer. (to be continued...)

Comment: The point is that with heap allocation, someone needs to own the created objects and that does not fit very well with common use of arithmetic operators. E.g. in `(a+b)+c`, the result of `a+b` would be a temporary object which should be destroyed as soon as it has been used in the expression. If the `+` operator returns a new object allocated on the heap, it will be difficult to get it removed in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the + operator for your class type. The parameters for your operator function are pointers.

You can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) about that. There is also an example for overloading the + operator.

> When an operator appears in an expression, and at least one of its operands has a class type or an enumeration type, then overload resolution is used to determine the user-defined function to be called among all the functions whose signatures match the following: See table in link.

To solve the issue, you can write:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    double data{};
    Node() {}
    Node(double x) : data(x) {}
    Node* add(Node* rhs);
};

// Works
Node* Node::add(Node* rhs) {
    Node* value = new Node();
    value->data = this->data + rhs->data;
    return value;
}
Node* operator+ (const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) {
    Node* value = new Node();
    value->data = lhs.data + rhs.data;
    return value;
}
//Does not work

int main(void) {

    Node* a = new Node(2.0);
    Node* b = new Node(3.0);

    Node* c = nullptr;
    //c = a->add(b); // this works
    c = *a + *b;  // does not work
    std::cout << c->data << "\n";

    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;

    return 0;
}
```